# Trying to append a column in numpy array, getting ValueError

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to append column for the following arrays

```
train = np.append(train_data, train_labels, axis=1)

(60000, 784)
(60000,)
```

And I get the error

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

I cannot understand what the issue is...
I need output of

```
(60000, 785)
```

Comment: What are your `train_data` and `train_labels`?

Comment: When given an `axis`, np.append` is just `np.concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)`.  When using `concatenate` the number of dimensions of the inputs has to match (in this case all must be 2d).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use axis=0.

```
>>> np.append((1,2),(2,),axis=0)
array([1, 2, 2])
```

If those tuples that you have posted are array shapes, then you can use

```
train = np.append(train_data, train_labels[:,None], axis=1)
```

The arrays must have the same number of dimensions (2 in this case). Using None in indexing for non-existing dimension adds a singleton dimension to a an array.

```
>>> train_labels[:,None].shape
(60000, 1)
```

Comment: with axis 0 I get the same error and I want to add column, axis 0 is for rows

Comment: @YohanRoth You are welcome. I added a bit of explanation (not very accurate, but you can check numpy docs on broadcasting for an accurate (but confusing) explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You should run

```
train = np.append(train_data, train_labels.reshape(-1, 1), axis=1)
```

That will fix your problem. 
Cheers